# HTML5 game objects and sharing methods

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas

I'm having some issues understanding the code below for HTML5 game. This what i think is happening and was wondering if my understanding is correct?

1) When the Entity function is called, the object SELF is created along with its method (test collision)

2) When the Enemy object is created, it calls the function 'actor' and INHERITS the functions from the SELF object (because self refers to itself) but it also INHERITS the perform.attack method

I'm not sure why we return the object, but in short, by creating the SELF object we can share methods, behaviors and properties allowing us to create DRY code?

I hope my understanding is correct?

```
Entity = function(type,id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height,color){
    // a function to call 
    var self = {
            type:type,
            x:x,
            spdX:spdX,
            y:y,
            spdY:spdY,
            width:width,
            height:height,
            color:color,
    };

    self.testCollision = function(entity2){
            var rect1 = {
                    x:self.x-self.width/2,
                    y:self.y-self.height/2,
                    width:self.width,
                    height:self.height,
            }
            var rect2 = {
                    x:entity2.x-entity2.width/2,
                    y:entity2.y-entity2.height/2,
                    width:entity2.width,
                    height:entity2.height,
            }
            return testCollisionRectRect(rect1,rect2);
    }

    return self;

}

//---------actor can be an enemy or player in the game-----//  


Actor = function(type,id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height,color){
    var self = Entity(type,id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height,color);

    self.attackCounter = 0;
    self.aimAngle = 0;
    self.atkSpd = 1;

    self.performAttack = function(){
            if(self.attackCounter > 25){    //every 1 sec
                    self.attackCounter = 0;
                    generateBullet(self);
            }
    }

    return self;
}


// ------------------Create the enemy function----------- //

Enemy = function(id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height){
    var self = Actor('enemy',id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height,'red');
    enemyList[id] = self;
}

randomlyGenerateEnemy = function(){
    //Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1
    var x = Math.random()*WIDTH;
    var y = Math.random()*HEIGHT;
    var height = 10 + Math.random()*30;     //between 10 and 40
    var width = 10 + Math.random()*30;
    var id = Math.random();
    var spdX = 5 + Math.random() * 5;
    var spdY = 5 + Math.random() * 5;
    Enemy(id,x,y,spdX,spdY,width,height);
}
```

Thank for the help.
P

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have native inheritance. JavaScript doesn't even classes to inherit from, yet -- but JS6 has classes.

`Entity` is a factory that creates & returns anonymous `self` objects with properties & a testCollision method.

`Actor` requests a new object from Entity. Actor adds properties & a performAttack method to the requested object and returns that extended object.

`Enemy` requests a new object from Actor. Enemy adds that object to an array.

**If we examine only this code**

If this is the only time Entity & Actor are used then the code is un-necessarily broken into parts. The entire final object (all properties & all methods included) could most efficiently be built in `randomlyGenerateEnemy`.

**If there is more code that uses Entity & Actor**

Presumably(!) ...

Entity creates the properties and methods that are common to all game pieces (pieces == characters, structures, etc). To borrow a math phrase, Entity creates an object with the "most common denominators".

Actor enhances the basic Entity object with properties and methods that are inherent to Actor game characters.

Enemy simply adds a new Actor object to the `enemyList`.

Presumably there might also be a `Structure` function which (like Actor) enhances the basic Entity object with properties and methods that are inherent to Structure game pieces.

Presumably there might also be a `Buildings` function which (like Enemy) simply adds a new Structure object to a `buildingsList`.

Since the Entity code is being reused by both Actor & Structure in the presumed code, the presumed code would make use of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) coding pattern.

Comment: Superb clarity!! thankyou, If i have any other questions, I will post